# Устранить ошибку с API key google map

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

На Wordpress сайт подключаю google map в файле `functions.php` так:

```
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIkey&callback=initMap', '', '',true);
```

На странице с картой все работает без проблем, но на других страницах консоль выводит ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of js?key=APIKey&callback=initMap&ver=4.7.5:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
```

Плагин для карт не использую.

Как исправить такую ошибку или как правильно подключить google map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключено правильно. Проблема в коде функции initMap. Она вызывается на всех страницах и ищет firstChild от какого-то элемента DOM, которого нет нигде, кроме страницы с картой. Поставьте проверку на существование этого элемента, и, если он не найден, не инициализируйте карту.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае функция вызывается два раза - один раз колбеком в ссылке, второй непосредственно в коде. Отсюда и ошибка. Если есть колбек, не нужно инициализировать функцию второй раз.